# What's the easiest way to populate a ReactJS select field with user names from a JSON object array?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to create my first project in React js and I need some help with select option.
So, I have this JSON data file:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Anton Tur",
      "username": "nosensejk"   
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Peggy Sonaya",
      "username": "Peggaya"      
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Joseph Maguire",
      "username": "Joemag"      
    }
  ],
  "transports": [
    {
      "id": "T1",
      "name": "MAZ 2105",
      "type": "bus"     
    },
    {
      "id": "T2",
      "name": "MAZ 2106",
      "type": "bus"     
    },
    {
      "id": "T3",
      "name": "MAZ 2205",
      "type": "trolleybus"      
    },
    {
      "id": "T4",
      "name": "MAZ 2307",
      "type": "tram",    
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone show me the easiest way to use a select field to display, for example, users' names? Thank you in advance.

Here is some code in my JS file

```
import React from 'react';
import db from './../../node_modules/server/db.json';


function calculate(){


  return(
  <div>
     <select>
      <option value="choose" disabled selected="selected">
         -- Select user --
      </option>
      {db.users.name}
      </select>
   </div>
  );
}
export default calculate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const data = {
  users: [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Anton Tur",
      username: "nosensejk"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Peggy Sonaya",
      username: "Peggaya"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Joseph Maguire",
      username: "Joemag"
    }
  ],
  transports: [
    {
      id: "T1",
      name: "MAZ 2105",
      type: "bus"
    },
    {
      id: "T2",
      name: "MAZ 2106",
      type: "bus"
    },
    {
      id: "T3",
      name: "MAZ 2205",
      type: "trolleybus"
    },
    {
      id: "T4",
      name: "MAZ 2307",
      type: "tram"
    }
  ]
};
export default function Calculate() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <select>
        {data.users.map((user) => {
          return <option key={user.id} value={user.id}>{user.name}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please keep in mind that component names should start with a capital such as Calculate